# How to print system.out.println("xyz") statements from logic method to GUI using Ajax

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets, textarea

```
Index.jsp

<form action="submitClick" method ="post"
<textarea> id="textarea" name="textarea" rows="25" cols="100">${result}</textarea>
<input type="submit">
```

SubmitClick.java //servlet class

```
public class SubmitClick extends HttpServlet{
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    MainLogicClass mainLogic = new MainLogicClass(); 
    String outputString = mainLogic.logicMethod();
    request.setAttribute("result", outputString);/* outputString is getting printed all at once. I 
       want to print one by one print statements on TextArea (on index.jsp)*/

    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request,response);
 }
}
```

MainLogicClass//different class, present in same package

```
    public class MainLogicClass{
      public String logicMethod(){
      System.out.println("Database Connection successful");
    // I want to print "Database Connection successful" on textarea which presents on index.jsp
    // Some arithmetic logic
    // Some backend logic
    System.out.println("Backend verification successful"); //this should be printed on textarea just 
    //below the above printed statement
    //More logic
   // And some more print statements.
    
    }
    }
```

How can I pass these print statements to my index.jsp using Ajax or any other alternative approach.

Comment: How about writing `click event` on button which will called ajax ?

Comment: @Swati: Nope, OP wants to async send data from server to client. Some sort of a "real time logger" on a webpage. Canonical solution for that is just using a websocket.